# Java - changing a method to a for/while loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I want to change the first method to a while and for loop. I have added the code below. Is this correct?

```
public String extractWordFour(String text){
        if(text.length()==0 || text.charAt(0) == ''){
            return "";
        } else {
            return text.charAt(0) + extractWordFour(text.substring(1));
        }
    }

public String extractWordFour(String text){
    int i=0;
    while (i<=text.length){
        return text.charAt(0) + extractWordFour(text.substring(i));
        i++;
    }
}

public String extractWordFour(String text){
    for(int i=0;i<=text.length();i++){
        return text.charAt(0) + text.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code does not compile.

Comment: or do i need to add `|| text.charAt(0) == ''` in the while loop test?

Comment: as for me, it looks weird. What is the purpose of the method?

Comment: its a question from a mock exam paper. I have copied the code directly from the paper. I think you need to show an understanding of for/while loops

Comment: nsc010, you currently have 3 methods all with the same method signature, `public String extractWordFour(String text)`.  This will not compile if they are in the same class.  What are you aiming to do with these methods?  Are they intended to be in separate classes?

Comment: @nsc010 Without knowing what the original code is supposed to do, difficult to say how it should be refactored. Is `text.charAt(0) == ''` supposed to be `text.charAt(0) == ' '`? (with a space)

Comment: the first method was given to me (i have no control over it). i made the for/while loops. The methods wouldn't be in the same class, but are just alternatives to the first method. The question only gives me the method and no further information, just that i need to convert it

Comment: @nsc010 What I'm saying is that `text.charAt(0) == ''` is not a valid Java statement (there is no such thing as an "empty char"). So I suppose it's a typo and you need to correct it, because depending on what that part really is, the refactoring will possibly be different.

Comment: A shorter way to do this is `return text.split(" ")[0];` but I assume your assignment expects you to use a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to answer this question because I think its a h.w. assignment but I'm putting it in an answer since I can't fit this in a comment, but I'm assuming you want to convert a recursive solution into a while or for loop solution.

Your while solution is wrong first of all because you are mixing recursion and while together. You should not be calling the function inside your while loop!

```
public String extractWordFour(String text){
    int i=0;
    while (i<=text.length){
        return text.charAt(0) + extractWordFour(text.substring(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

This one can't finish because you are returning it before its even looped more than once.

```
public String extractWordFour(String text){
    for(int i=0;i<=text.length();i++){
        return text.charAt(0) + text.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Anyways hope that helps. The best thing to do would be to fully understand what the first function does, write it down and then think about how to make it do the exact same thing with a while or a for loop.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, i'll give it another go

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you can't have `String.charAt(0) == ''` because `''` isn't a valid character, unlike `""` for an empty String which is valid.

Your second method doesn't work because it should be `text.length()` instead of `text.length` which is the method when you're calling it on an array, as well as the `i++` being unreachable because of the recursion. And failing that, the method signature claims it returns a String, but there is no return statement.

Your third method does have a return statement, but it still wouldn't work because it'll just return on the first iteration and therefore only give you the first 2 characters (and in fact your compiler won't even allow it because it won't realise this).

Aside from all these issues, if the method name of `extractWordFour` is an accurate representation of what they should do, none of them will because the logic makes no sense. I suggest you start by thinking about that: How can you tell when one word ends by examining the String, and what does your program need to know to remove everything before the fourth word, and everything after it?

Comment: The third method will actually return the entire text - the very first character followed by everything after the first character.